# if (error) throw error d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I keep seeing this in every single example in the d3.js documentation. [This treemap example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) has it as well:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
        .eachBefore(function(d) { d.data.id = (d.parent ? d.parent.data.id + "." : "") + d.data.name; })
        .sum(sumBySize)
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value; });

    //and so on
```

I assumed, it will assist with handling errors, however, I tried with a `json file` with no values and I still get an error: **d3.v4.min.js:2 Error:  attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(0, NaN)"**

Comment: This line that appears in many d3 examples almost always appears below d3.json or d3.csv, methods that load files - where it will tell you the error in loading the file, not errors in other parts of your code, such as not a number (NaN) errors. Your error comes from something you are passing d3, which is why the error is in a line in d3.v4.min.js not the line with the `if(error) throw error;` is.

Answer (score -1):

Throwing an error with the `throw` keyword just means you get to define an error, it doesn't act like a try/catch. Look at this:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: I still do not understand how will that single line of code `if (error) throw error;` contribute in any way.

Comment: Well, if you know there's a possibility of an error happening, it would be a lot more helpful to show that error the way it makes the most sense for debugging, instead of letting it fall through and showing some potentially not-so helpful js error.